# Add patchset to someone elses commit in Gerrit

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit, git-amend

so i am trying to add some files to a commit made by someone else.

Specifically I am using Jenkins to run some tests and when they are done I want to amend the resulting files of my tests to the original commit so the test results will be merged if the commit is successfully reviewed and merged.

Right now I have a build.sh script which will be executed by jenkins (jenkins is triggered automatically on each commit pushed to gerrit):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Starting
python /some/folders/test.py
echo Tests finished, adding results
git add /some/folders/results/
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
echo Done
```

The problem is this fails. Is this the right way to amend files to a commit made by someone else?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Has the Jenkins user "Add Patch Set" permission?

See more details [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_add_patch_set).

Answer (score 0):

There is *no* "right" way to amend a commit that's been pushed.  Amending a commit is the same as rebasing.

I'll bet what's failing is the push, and it's telling you something about updating a remote ref that isn't the ancestor, right?  That's because anyone with a ref pointing to the other guy's commit (or any descendant of it) will be put in a broken state if you do what you're trying to do.

If you insist on doing it anyway, you need to push with the `-f` option and then get ready to spend the next week helping your coworkers fix what you've done to them.

Probably better to figure out a different way to get the desired result.